# Why can‘t I use the VGA port of my Lenovo W530 Laptop under Xubuntu 18.04?

Tags: nvidia, multiple-monitors, display, xrandr, vga

I have a Lenovo W530 laptop and it runs Xubuntu 18.04.4 LTS currently with kernel 5.3.0-40-generic x86_64. xrandr has version 1.5.0 and the version of RandR is 1.5.

My problem: **I can’t use an external screen attached through the VGA port** – neither when it is connected directly to the laptop outside of the docking station nor when it is connected to the VGA port of the docking station when the laptop is seated in it. However, under Windows 10, I can use the external screen in both situations. (Under Windows, the VGA port of the laptop itself does not work properly when the laptop is in the docking station. That does not prevent using the VGA port completely like under Xubuntu 18.04). - If I remember right, the VGA port has worked before uner Xubuntu 16.04, but I have no chance to check that right now.

Under Windows 10 I can use a second screen attached to the VGA port. It is even possible to control three screens by the W530 laptop: the builtin laptop screen, another screen attached through VGA and yet another screen attached through DP (with an adapter DP1-HDMI). In this situation, the builtin laptop screen is controlled by the Intel HD Graphics 4000, the other two screens are controlled by the NVIDIA Quadro K1000M Version 80.7.32.0.f, according to Windows.

The integrated NVIDIA Graphics of the computer is activated in the BIOS. There is a file `/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/11-nvidia-prime.conf` and its content is

```
# DO NOT EDIT. AUTOMATICALLY GENERATED BY gpu-manager

Section "OutputClass"
  Identifier "Nvidia Prime"
  MatchDriver "nvidia-drm"
  Driver "nvidia"
  Option "AllowEmptyInitialConfiguration"
  Option "IgnoreDisplayDevices" "CRT"
  Option "PrimaryGPU" "Yes"
  ModulePath "/x86_64-linux-gnu/nvidia/xorg"
EndSection
```

One hint I found when looking for other solutions, was to put a # in front of the line

```
Option "IgnoreDisplayDevices" "CRT"
```

to deactivate it. I did that although I saw the warning at the beginning of the file. This hint did not work. When I looked at this file later, I saw that the # had vanished, so probably it did not survive when I made my test and perhaps it had already gone at my test. The warning at the beginning of the file seems to be fully justified.

`lscpi` tells me:

```
a@v:~$  lspci | grep -i vga
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 3rd Gen Core processor Graphics 
Controller (rev 09)
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GK107GLM [Quadro K1000M] (rev a1)
a@v:~$
```

`xrandr` tells me:

`a@v:~$ xrandr --prop
Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 1920 x 1080, maximum 16384 x 16384
LVDS-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
    CscMatrix: 65536 0 0 0 0 65536 0 0 0 0 65536 0 
    BorderDimensions: 4 
        supported: 4
    Border: 0 0 0 0 
        range: (0, 65535)
    SignalFormat: LVDS 
        supported: LVDS
    ConnectorType: Panel 
    ConnectorNumber: 0 
    _ConnectorLocation: 0 
    non-desktop: 0 
        supported: 0, 1
DP-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
    CscMatrix: 65536 0 0 0 0 65536 0 0 0 0 65536 0 
    BorderDimensions: 4 
        supported: 4
    Border: 0 0 0 0 
        range: (0, 65535)
    SignalFormat: TMDS 
        supported: TMDS
    ConnectorType: DisplayPort 
    ConnectorNumber: 2 
    _ConnectorLocation: 2 
    non-desktop: 0 
        supported: 0, 1
DP-1 connected 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 698mm x 392mm
    CscMatrix: 65536 0 0 0 0 65536 0 0 0 0 65536 0 
    EDID: 
        00ffffffffffff0034a996a201010101
        00180103808048780adaffa3584aa229
        17494b21080031404540614081800101
        010101010101023a80d072382d40102c
        4580ba882100001e023a801871382d40
        582c4500ba882100001e000000fc0050
        616e61736f6e69632d54560a000000fd
        00173d0f440f000a202020202020015a
        020322f24d9f90140520212213041203
        16072309070168030c001000b8260fe2
        004b011d80d0721c1620102c2580ba88
        2100009e011d8018711c1620582c2500
        ba882100009e011d00bc52d01e20b828
        5540ba882100001e662156aa51001e30
        468f3300ba882100001e000000000000
        000000000000000000000000000000bb
    BorderDimensions: 4 
        supported: 4
    Border: 0 0 0 0 
        range: (0, 65535)
    SignalFormat: TMDS 
        supported: TMDS
    ConnectorType: DisplayPort 
    ConnectorNumber: 3 
    _ConnectorLocation: 3 
    non-desktop: 0 
        supported: 0, 1
   1920x1080     50.00*+  60.00    59.94    29.97    25.00    23.98    60.05    60.00    50.04
   1366x768      59.79
   1280x1024     60.02
   1280x720      59.94    50.00
   1024x768      60.00
   800x600       60.32
   720x576       50.00
   720x480       59.94
   640x480       59.95    59.94
DP-2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
    CscMatrix: 65536 0 0 0 0 65536 0 0 0 0 65536 0 
    BorderDimensions: 4 
        supported: 4
    Border: 0 0 0 0 
        range: (0, 65535)
    SignalFormat: TMDS 
        supported: TMDS
    ConnectorType: DisplayPort 
    ConnectorNumber: 4 
    _ConnectorLocation: 4 
    non-desktop: 0 
        supported: 0, 1
DP-3 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
    CscMatrix: 65536 0 0 0 0 65536 0 0 0 0 65536 0 
    BorderDimensions: 4 
        supported: 4
    Border: 0 0 0 0 
        range: (0, 65535)
    SignalFormat: DisplayPort 
        supported: DisplayPort
    ConnectorType: DisplayPort 
    ConnectorNumber: 2 
    _ConnectorLocation: 2 
    non-desktop: 0 
        supported: 0, 1
DP-4 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
    CscMatrix: 65536 0 0 0 0 65536 0 0 0 0 65536 0 
    BorderDimensions: 4 
        supported: 4
    Border: 0 0 0 0 
        range: (0, 65535)
    SignalFormat: DisplayPort 
        supported: DisplayPort
    ConnectorType: DisplayPort 
    ConnectorNumber: 3 
    _ConnectorLocation: 3 
    non-desktop: 0 
        supported: 0, 1
DP-5 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
    CscMatrix: 65536 0 0 0 0 65536 0 0 0 0 65536 0 
    BorderDimensions: 4 
        supported: 4
    Border: 0 0 0 0 
        range: (0, 65535)
    SignalFormat: DisplayPort 
        supported: DisplayPort
    ConnectorType: DisplayPort 
    ConnectorNumber: 4 
    _ConnectorLocation: 4 
    non-desktop: 0 
        supported: 0, 1
LVDS-1-1 connected primary 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 344mm x 193mm
    EDID: 
        00ffffffffffff0030aeb24000000000
        0113010380221378ea2135ad5037aa24
        11505400000001010101010101010101
        0101010101014c368082703832403c30
        aa0058c1100000183f2d808270383240
        3c30aa0058c1100000180000000f00d1
        0932d109281b190006af5634000000fe
        004231353648573031205634200a00d6
    PRIME Synchronization: 0 
        supported: 0, 1
    scaling mode: Full aspect 
        supported: Full, Center, Full aspect
    link-status: Good 
        supported: Good, Bad
    CONNECTOR_ID: 67 
        supported: 67
    non-desktop: 0 
        range: (0, 1)
   1920x1080     60.00*+  59.97    59.96    59.93    50.00
   1680x1050     59.95    59.88
   1600x1024     60.17
   1400x1050     59.98
   1600x900      59.99    59.94    59.95    59.82
   1280x1024     60.02
   1440x900      59.89
   1400x900      59.96    59.88
   1280x960      60.00
   1440x810      60.00    59.97
   1368x768      59.88    59.85
   1360x768      59.80    59.96
   1280x800      59.99    59.97    59.81    59.91
   1152x864      60.00
   1280x720      60.00    59.99    59.86    59.74
   960x720       60.00
   928x696       60.05
   896x672       60.01
   1024x576      59.95    59.96    59.90    59.82
   960x600       59.93    60.00
   960x540       59.96    59.99    59.63    59.82
   800x600       60.00    60.32    56.25
   840x525       60.01    59.88
   864x486       59.92    59.57
   800x512       60.17
   700x525       59.98
   800x450       59.95    59.82
   640x512       60.02
   720x450       59.89
   700x450       59.96    59.88
   640x480       60.00    59.94
   720x405       59.51    58.99
   684x384       59.88    59.85
   680x384       59.80    59.96
   640x400       59.88    59.98
   576x432       60.06
   640x360       59.86    59.83    59.84    59.32
   512x384       60.00
   512x288       60.00    59.92
   480x270       59.63    59.82
   400x300       60.32    56.34
   432x243       59.92    59.57
   320x240       60.05
   360x202       59.51    59.13
   320x180       59.84    59.32
VGA-1-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
    PRIME Synchronization: 1 
        supported: 0, 1
    link-status: Good 
        supported: Good, Bad
    CONNECTOR_ID: 71 
        supported: 71
    non-desktop: 0 
        range: (0, 1)
  1280x1024 (0x52) 108.000MHz +HSync +VSync
        h: width  1280 start 1328 end 1440 total 1688 skew    0 clock  63.98KHz
        v: height 1024 start 1025 end 1028 total 1066           clock  60.02Hz
  1024x768 (0x67) 65.000MHz -HSync -VSync
        h: width  1024 start 1048 end 1184 total 1344 skew    0 clock  48.36KHz
        v: height  768 start  771 end  777 total  806           clock  60.00Hz
  800x600 (0x76) 40.000MHz +HSync +VSync
        h: width   800 start  840 end  968 total 1056 skew    0 clock  37.88KHz
        v: height  600 start  601 end  605 total  628           clock  60.32Hz
  640x480 (0x85) 25.175MHz -HSync -VSync
        h: width   640 start  656 end  752 total  800 skew    0 clock  31.47KHz
        v: height  480 start  490 end  492 total  525           clock  59.94Hz
a@v:~$`

i.e. it sees the internal screen and the one connected through DP1 but it sees the VGA-1-1 disconnected. Despite of that, it detects the VGA screen's supported resolutions. **That’s really strange.**  Sometimes (e.g. when I start the computer without the other screen connected through DP1), it is also found VGA-1-1 disconnected, but then the lines with the possible screen resolutions of it are missing.

When looking at the screen settings under Xubuntu in the GUI, it dos not offer me the screen which is connected by VGA. The same holds for the NVIDIA X Server Settings app.

The LED on the VGA screen‘s power switch remains yellow. Normally it turns green when Sync signals are seen by the VGA screen's electronics.

**Why does VGA-1-1 appear as disconnected although it is connected and the screen is powered on?**

**What‘s necessary to use the VGA port e.g. for a projector under Xubuntu?**

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue on a W520 running Ubuntu 20.04, while using the NVIDIA driver.

I found a workaround by commenting out the

```
Option "IgnoreDisplayDevices" "CRT"
```

line in the `/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/11-nvidia-prime.conf` configuration file by putting a # in front.

In order to prevent this change to be overwritten by `gpu-manager`, I also edited  the `/etc/default/grub` configuration file by changing the line

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
```

to

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash nogpumanager"
```

and then running

```
sudo update-grub
```

in the terminal in order to update the Grub configuration. After rebooting I had a working VGA port.

(Interestingly the connected monitor appears as `VGA-0` in the output of `xrandr`, while `VGA-1-1` still appears as disconnected -- before the modification `xrandr` did not even list `VGA-0` as an option.)